# Customize list output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
sampleList=['a','b','c','d']
```

I need to display the list elements as follows:

```
a, b, c and d
```

I tried to join ',' with each list element. However I couldn't get the expected result.

```
','.join(sampleList)
```

Each list element is separated by comma and keyword 'and' prior to last element like a, b, c and d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not built-in way to do that. You have to DIY

```
', '.join(sampleList[:-1]) + ' and ' + str(sampleList[-1])
```

Output:

```
>>> sampleList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> ', '.join(sampleList[:-1]) + ' and ' + str(sampleList[-1])
'a, b, c and d'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using `str.join`, reversing with `[::-1]` and `str.replace` (it's kinda a hack):

```
>>> sampleList=['a','b','c','d']
>>> s = ', '.join(sampleList)
>>> s[::-1].replace(' ,', ' dna ', 1)[::-1]
'a, b, c and d'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can do the same for n-1 elements and concatenate the last element by 'and':

```
L=['a','b','c','d']
l=L[:-1] #get all except the last element
st=l.join(',')
sf= st+' and '+L[-1]
#sf=a,b,c and d
```